# How to sort the fields when the numbers are entered as strings,in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is a sample of the document I have indexed using elasticsearch.

```
{

"itemName": "refridgirator"
"brand": "samsung"
"price": "1600"
"emi": "40"
"location":"Brisbane"
}
```

As you can see from the above document that,all the numerical fields such as "price" and "emi" are entered as strings. Now as I need to sort my indexed documents in the basis of this value,Im not able to do that. How can I make it done?

Comment: If you have a mapping type, how does it look like? Also can you show us the command you used to index your documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the mapping , you need to specify this as long or int.
That way , the number would be stored as long in the reverse index and field data cache and actual number sort will work out -

```
curl -X PUT "http://$hostname:9200/your_index/your_type/_mapping" -d '{
  "yout_type": {
    "properties": {
      "price": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

You can find more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html).
Also an alternate method by parsing string values have been discussed in detail in this [blog](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-scripting-sorting)

Comment: Note that this will not work if your `price` field is already mapped as a `string`. It will throw `"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [price] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [long]]}]",`

Comment: @Vineeth Mohan I have the same situation, but only this way I have a numeric string field, seperated with dots, like "1.1.2", "11.2.1", and the like. I have a requirement to do sorting by this field, and when I try to sort by that field, it does String sorting.

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan - Use a script sort , in the script take each number and multiply by 1000 , 100 , 10 and then sort based on the weighted sum

So 11.2.1 -> 11 * 1000 + 2 * 100 + 1 * 10 -> 110110 , sort based on this

Answer (score 1):

In your mapping, you need to declare the `price` and `emi` fields as [number type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#number) (double, float, integer, etc) like this:

```
// remove the current index
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/your_index

// create the index anew
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "itemName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "brand": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "emi": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And then when you re-index your documents, make sure the `price` and `emi` fields in your JSON are numbers as well and not strings (i.e. without the double quotes):

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/123 -d '
{
  "itemName": "refridgirator",
  "brand": "samsung",
  "price": 1600,
  "emi": 40,
  "location": "Brisbane"
}'
```